# AccessDenied when sending Encrypt request to Amazon KMS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms

I want to encrypt a string using Amazon KMS services. My credentials work, I can use the client to get a list of keys, but I get a 400 when I try to encrypt my string. This is my code (I bet I'm missing something simple):

```
public static string Encrypt(string str, string awsRegion, string theKey)
{
     var keyId = "arn:aws:kms:" + awsRegion + ":0987654321:key/" + thekey;

     using (var client = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient(AWSId, AWSSK, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))            
     {
          var req = new EncryptRequest
          {
               KeyId = keyId,
               Plaintext = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str))
          };

          var blob = client.Encrypt(req).CiphertextBlob;
          return new StreamReader(blob).ReadToEnd();
     }
}
```

What could be the cause of this?

I also have my profile set up in visual studio.

Edit 1: The error message is:

> Error making request with Error Code AccessDeniedException and Http
>   Status Code BadRequest. No further error information was returned by
>   the service.

Comment: what is the error message associated with the 400?

Comment: I'll update the question, the associated error message is:
Error making request with Error Code AccessDeniedException and Http Status Code BadRequest. No further error information was returned by the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that integer that's between the region and key in the keyId string isn't arbitrary.

I got it working by getting the list of keys that are available to me, finding the corresponding key and copying that integer into my keyId string in-place of the 0987654321.

Comment: that number is your account id :)